# Angular 1.2 rc, ngAnimate - is this release viable?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

What version of Angular should I really be using here if I want to animate reliably?

See the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DjaybiZ8HJViyWOeWCwE?p=preview)

**Update:**

This was a case of not working on my machine, also the Plunker has been updated to remove a couple issues.

Comment: Your Plunker script has worked perfectly for me. FWIW I'm using Chrome  v29.0.1547.65.

Comment: Works also perfectly with Firefox 23.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to animate reliably then you need the 1.2 branch.  However, at time of writing Angular 1.2 is at the release candidate stage so you need to be careful if you are considering putting this in to production in the near future.